# Most pythonic way to group an iterator in blocks of size n

Tags: python, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

If you have an iterator `iter` with values `i0, i1, i2, ...`, what's the most Pythonic way to get an iterator whose values are

```
[i0, i1, i2], [i3, i4, i5], ...
```

The above would be the output to a hypothetical `groupby(iter, 3)`.

Comment: More specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/312644/989121) which applies to arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 2):

The itertools module has a recipe for this called [`grouper`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes). Here is the excerpt copied straight from itertools documentation.

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: Coming to think of it, it's exactly similar to the solution provided by @user792036

Comment: Actually this covers a fill value and looks nicer when used since it's a function.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I can find (requires `itertools`):

```
groupby = lambda s,n : izip(*[iter(s)]*n)
```

but it feels slightly hacky and is hard to read

Comment: That does not solve the problem in a general way for inputs that are not a multiple of the block size. izip basically ignores the last, not full, block of items.